# Custom checkboxes

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've coded a little simple script that allows me to use custom checkboxes. It works fine on FF, Opera and webkit based browsers but, as usual, IE is giving me headhaches.

The behaviour on IE is really strange, it seems like it's checking and unchecking random boxes on each click. Well, maybe it's not but I really don't see any consistency.

You can view the code and test it by yourself on http://i5.be/EX. The example is written in HTML5 and having also tested it in good old XHTML1.0, the issue is unfortunately the same. Thus, the problem is not due to the HTML5 doctype.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Cheers,
Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point, I would use the `click` event instead of the `change` event. Try:

```
  $("body")
    .addClass(settings.bodyJsClass)
    .find(":checkbox")
    .filter("." + settings.customClass)
    .each(styleCheckStatus)
    .click(styleCheckStatus);
```

Comment: `.find(":checkbox").filter("." + settings.customClass)` could be reduced to one call: `.find("." + settings.customClass + ":checkbox)` which might even be faster since browsers now optimise for finding elements by class name.

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing the onblur event issue, everything works well now!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the IE6 `onChange` event where it doesn't fire until the checkbox loses focus (specifically, when the `onBlur` event fires). You can test it on your page by clicking one of the boxes, then clicking somewhere else.

One fix would be to attach the entire event to the `label` instead (Most elegant solution).

Alternatively, you could take it into your own hands and execute the `onClick` and `onBlur` events of the checkbox manually when a label is clicked. This is an unobstrusive solution and shouldn't require any changes to your existing code.

```
  $("label").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#" + $(this).attr("for")).click().blur();
  });
```

Not tested but you get the idea :)

Comment: Actually, clicking the labels or the checkboxes is the same since they're linked by the for and id attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event for checkboxes is only fired when you click the checkbox twice. So, indeed use the `click` event. This also applies on radio buttons by the way.

Answer (score -1):

Here is something to help you. I spent a couple hours making them:

### Radio buttons:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var radioButtonGroups = document.getElementsByClassName('radioGroupContainer');
  for (var i = 0; i != radioButtonGroups.length; i++) {
    var radioButtons = radioButtonGroups[i].getElementsByClassName('radioButtonContainer');
    for (var i = 0; i != radioButtons.length; i++) {
      radioButtons[i].onclick = function() {
        var value = this.children[0].getAttribute('name');
        for (var i = 0; i != radioButtons.length; i++) {
          radioButtons[i].children[0].setAttribute('class', 'radioButtonDot');
        }
        this.children[0].setAttribute('class', 'radioButtonDotActive');
        this.parentNode.setAttribute('name', value);
      };
    }
  }
};
```

```css
/*
* Created by William Green.
* Questions or comments? Email william.green@protonmail.com
* I would appreciate credit for this code if you use it; but it is not required.
* Last updated July 26, 2015
* Created July 26, 2015
*
*/

.radioButtonContainer {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: table;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.radioButtonContainer .radioButtonDot {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.radioButtonContainer .radioButtonDotActive {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #1396DE;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.radioButtonContainer .radioButtonLabel {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  vertidal-align: middle;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioGroupContainer" id="radioChoicesOne">
  <div class="radioButtonContainer">
    <div class="radioButtonDot" name="optionOne"></div>
    <input type="button" class="radioButtonLabel" value="Option One">
  </div>
  <div class="radioButtonContainer">
    <div class="radioButtonDot" name="optionTwo"></div>
    <input type="button" class="radioButtonLabel" value="Option Two">
  </div>
  <div class="radioButtonContainer">
    <div class="radioButtonDot" name="optionThree"></div>
    <input type="button" class="radioButtonLabel" value="Option Three">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="radioButtonGroupOneValue"></div>
<input type="button" value="Get radio button value..." onclick="document.getElementById('radioButtonGroupOneValue').innerHTML = document.getElementById('radioChoicesOne').getAttribute('name');">
```

### Checkboxes:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  for (var i = 0; i != checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].hasAttribute('name') == false) {
      checkboxes[i].setAttribute('name', 'notChecked');
    } else {
      if (checkboxes[i].getAttribute('name') == 'checked') {
        checkboxes[i].setAttribute('name', 'checked');
        checkboxes[i].children[0].className = 'checkboxDotActive';
      }
    }

    checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
      if (this.getAttribute('name') == 'checked') {
        this.setAttribute('name', 'notChecked');
        this.children[0].className = 'checkboxDot';
      } else {
        this.setAttribute('name', 'checked');
        this.children[0].className = 'checkboxDotActive';
      }
    };
  }
};
```

```css
/*
* Questions or comments? Please email william.green@protonmail.com
* Credit for this project goes to William Green (me).
* Created July 25, 2015
* Last updated July 25, 2015
* I would like appropriate credit for this code, although it is not required.
*
* Thank you for looking, hope you find it useful.
* Please come back, since I may be adding more features to the code to allow for advanced functionality.
*
* PLEASE NOTE THAT THE 'checkboxDot' DIV MUST COME BEFORE ANY OTHER INNER MARKUP.
* IT MUST COME IMMEDIATELY AFTER THE PARENT DIV! IT WILL NOT WORK OTHERWISE!!!
*
* Thank you for showing interest in this code!
*/

/*IMPORTANT STYLES... THE STYLES LATER ARE NOT DIRECTLY RELATED THE THE CHECKBOXES*/

.checkbox {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: table;
}
.checkbox input {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.checkbox .checkboxDot {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.checkbox .checkboxDotActive {
  background-color: #01A1DB;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
/*END IMPORTANT STYLES*/

/*START IRRELEVANT STYLES*/

.valueButton {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
/*END IRRELEVANT STYLES*/
```

```html
<h1>Javascript, html, and css checkboes -- best browser support ever!</h1>


<h3>Normal checkbox</h3>

<div id="checkboxOne" class="checkbox">
  <div class="checkboxDot"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Item 1">
</div>
<div id="checkboxOneStatus"></div>
<input type="button" class="valueButton" onclick="document.getElementById('checkboxOneStatus').innerHTML = document.getElementById('checkboxOne').getAttribute('name');" value="Is it checked?">

<h3>Checked by default</h3> 
<div id="checkboxTwo" class="checkbox" name="checked">
  <div class="checkboxDot"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Item 2">
</div>
<div id="checkboxTwoStatus"></div>
<input type="button" class="valueButton" onclick="document.getElementById('checkboxTwoStatus').innerHTML = document.getElementById('checkboxTwo').getAttribute('name');" value="Is it checked?">
```

Comment: I created the page for this purpose. There are so many people who have trouble with this (including me) that I created the page to illustrate a solution. I once did a search on SO for custom radio/checkboxes and there were dozens of questions that my code snippet could s love the problem.